# Getting the Value using an index on an Object Hashmap

Tags: javascript, hashmap

As far as i know, unlike arrays object hashmaps use literal keys to query the value, Is it possible to query the object hashmap using an index like one would do on arrays? I know this is possible using frameworks like underscore.js but i just want a vanilla javascript method if by any chance its possible.

Comment: The order of keys in an Object is undefined, so it wouldn't be reliable. Unless by access by index you mean `myobject[2]` where the object looks like `{ 1 : 'one', 2 : 'two' }` then of course it's possible to use integers instead of strings as keys.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Arrays are the kind of data structure which is defined loosely as collection of values (may be of different types in JS) whereas Object or hashmaps (traditionally) are a record of key-value pairs i.e. a value mapped to a key.

So in Arrays can be accessed by an index, but Objects are a type in themselves. But you surely can have an array of Objects which you can access by index.

Hope this answers your query.